# Automatically restore breakpoint ignore count in Eclipse

Tags: c++, debugging, eclipse-cdt

Breakpoint ignore count in Eclipse breakpoint properties decreases with each pass over breakpoint until it reaches zero. On the next debug launch you have to manually restore ignore count if you wish to stop there again. Is it possible to restore the ignore count to the initial value automatically when the debugger is stopped?

Eclipse version: 4.7.1a

Comment: Did you mean _"Hit Count"_? But the _Hit Count_ of a breakpoint is not decreased. With the Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a) I'm not able to reproduce your issue (Hello World surrounded by `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {...}` and a breakpoint with a hit count of `3`), it works as expected (hit count value will not be changed and every time debugging it, it stops at `i=2`). If this is different in your IDE, which plug-ins do you have installed?

Comment: No, it's "Ignore count". Maybe it's different for Java, because I'm on C++. Will change the question accordingly. Eclipse Marketplace window shows that no plugins are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **known issue** of Eclipse CDT:

[Eclipse bug 487053 - Breakpoint's "Ignore count" value changes when the breakpoint is hit](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487053)

As workaround, you can **import breakpoints** (right-click in the *Breakpoints* view and choose *Import Breakpoints...*) that have been exported before the *ignore counts* have been decreased with the option ***Update existing breakpoints***.